# Unable to create Jest tests for generation 2 package

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

I have created an LWC app, and am now trying to add code test coverage. But unfortunately, Jest (@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest@1.1.1) is failing in two different ways:

1. I use the `getRecords` wire adapter, which I think was added fairly recently (we're using api version 55). But Jest throws this error:

```
TypeError: Invalid adapterId, it must be extensible.
```

The other wire adapters, such as `getRecord`, are fine. Only the inclusion of this adapter causes this problem.

2. The `uiRelatedListApi` and `LightningConfirm` libraries result in errors like this:

```
Cannot find module 'lightning/uiRelatedListApi' from '<snip>'
```

No other `lightning/*` module causes this problem.

Any ideas what is causing this?

One thing I have noticed is that my project (derived from a recipe project), includes a Typescript type declaration file called **lds.d.ts**, and each of the types above which are causing problems do not exist in this file. The others, which are working fine, do exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I can't see your test code and wonder what a TypeScript type declaration file exists for, here are some hints that might help you:

Please check the official [LWC Recipes](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes) repository for a whole set of LWC Jest unit test examples. It uses `@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest@1.1.2` at the moment. Many of the standard Lightning APIs and dependencies are replaced with [jest-mocks](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/main/force-app/test/jest-mocks) here. For example, also the `getRecord` and `getRecords` actions from the `uiRecordApi` you mentioned:

https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/main/force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning/uiRecordApi.js

For the LightningConfirm you can also find an example on how to use / mock this in your Jest tests in the official LWC Component Reference:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-confirm/documentation

I hope this helps you to resolve your test issues.